Why i keep getting error trying to sideload using adb
I am trying to sideload apk to my device but im getting this error tried to surfe the internet for some explination and solutoins but couldnt find any ill try my luck here
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3007]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\user\Desktop\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
10f6af35        device


C:\Users\user\Desktop\platform-tools>adb install YouTube_19.14.42_Apkpure.apk
adb: failed to run abb_exec. Error: closed
adb: retrieving the default device installation mode failed: closedPerforming Streamed Install
adb: failed to run abb_exec. Error: closed
adb: connect error for write: closed



and another question is how can i tell adb to install a specific apk to a specific path
i tried to surf the internet for a solution with no succes.
i updated my drivers and adb.
i changed apk to see if its an apk problem still didnt work

adb install is a combination of multiple adb commands:

upload the apk
install it using pm install command.

Based on the error message it seems uploading is somehow the problem. Therefore I would suggest the workaround to upload the APK using a different way to the phone (e.g. via USB file sharing aka MTP) and then execute adb shell pm install <path to apkfile> from your PC.
Alternatively after uploading the APK you should be able to install the APK file by using an Android file manager.

Hi i already did pm push the apk file to my car but the problem is that i cant accsess the file manager neither package installer they are locked even tho i can see them in the system but with no accsess to them so im trying to use adb to install my apk

@Nath So adb shell doesn't work on your device?  If not then may be package installer is also not available on your device thus adb installfails.

it does work i can see everything in the car i just dont have access to them i am also trying to install using wirless adb but also getting errors with connections
